# Tracking of detected faces using OpenCV on iOS

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, opencv, computer-vision

**First, a quick bit of background**: I am fairly new to iOS and am attempting to detect faces using OpenCV on an iOS device. I was able to get the iOS openCV sample code working fine using the sample code here:

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/ios/video_processing/video_processing.html#opencviosvideoprocessing

This results in a useful method that is called for each frame polled from the camera:

```
- (void)processImage:(Mat&)image;
{
    // Do some OpenCV stuff with the image
    Mat image_copy;
    cvtColor(image, image_copy, CV_BGRA2BGR);

    // invert image
    bitwise_not(image_copy, image_copy);
    cvtColor(image_copy, image, CV_BGR2BGRA);
}
```

In this example, it successfully inverted the frame from the camera and displays on the device. This is useful, as I can subsitute my won OpenCV C++ code into here for whatever image processing I want to do with the frame.

Now, I wish to get face tracking implemented. There are header files for a detection based tracker in OpenCV 2.4.2 onwards called “opencv2/contrib/detection_based_tracker.hpp”. It defines a class called DetectionBasedTracker. The tracking mechanism it defines uses haar cascades in the background to detect objects. The reason that I wish to use this temporal tracking method rather than frame by frame face detection is that the tracking is much faster than the OpenCV Haar implementation. A guide on how to implement it is demonstrated here:
http://bytesandlogics.wordpress.com/2012/08/23/detectionbasedtracker-opencv-implementation/

I had success in implementing this code in C on an Android device. The main code is as follows:

```
DetectionBasedTracker::Parameters param;
param.maxObjectSize = 400;
param.maxTrackLifetime = 20;
param.minDetectionPeriod = 7;
param.minNeighbors = 3;
param.minObjectSize = 20;
param.scaleFactor = 1.1;

// The object needs to be defined using the constructor with the above 
// declared parameter structure. Then the object.run() method is called 
// to initialize the tracking.
DetectionBasedTracker obj = DetectionBasedTracker("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml",param);
obj.run();
```

And so, for each frame, I can process it to detect the bounding boxes of faces using the lines:

```
obj.process(gray_frame);
vector< Rect_<int> > faces;
obj.getObjects(faces);
```

**Now, the issue.** In Objective C, how to I create the "DetectionBasedTracker obj" object so that it can be used in the "- (void)processImage:(Mat&)image;" method? I do not know what calls the processImage method so I do not now if I can pass it that way. Is there a way to make the  "DetectionBasedTracker obj" global? and if so, how would I do that, and is this the correct way of doing it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you only need to detect faces you can use the native Core Image:http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_detect_faces/ci_detect_faces.html

Comment: Cheers for the response! I know about the native core, but I wish to develop this app for all iOS devices with a forward facing camera. The Apple face detection works great for the iPhone 4S and above (they are hardware accelerated), but is unfortunately just too slow for video on the iPhone 4 :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your view controller implementation is in objective-c++ (it says so on your first link) , and if you use as compiler Apple LLVM 2.0 or later, you can use c++ code everywhere in your obj-c++ implementation file (extension .mm).  Import you c++ headers and declare all your class-wide variables there rather than in the interface file like so:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "DetectionBasedTracker.h"


//class extension in your implementation file where your c++ variables go
@interface ViewController()
{
    DetectionBasedTracker myTracker();
}
@end

@implementation ViewController 

#pragma mark - Protocol CvVideoCameraDelegate

- (void)processImage:(Mat&)image;
{
    //...
    myTracker.doSomething();
    //...
}


@end
```